# Route does not detect the ajax url

Tags: laravel, export

I am doing the download and connecting ajax with the controller using controller. However, I am not sure why when I click the button, it only detect controller and ignore ajax url.

Route:

```
Route::get('filter-export', 'FiltersController@excel')->name('download');
```

Ajax connected by url 'filter-export':

```
$('#download').click(function(){
      var age = $('#age').val();

      ...


    });
```

Comment: Your button blade where's the start tag for the `button`?

Comment: updated code in question

Comment: Route::get('/filter-export', 'FiltersController@excel')->name('download'); in web.php and in ajax url: "/filter-export",

Comment: tried this, its not working

Comment: Add a slash to the ajax url `url: "/filter-export",`

Comment: added, but not working as well

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting `$('#download')` for the click event however your `<a>` does not have an id so you should add `id="download"` to the `<a>`

Also, If you intend the "filter-export" URL to only be used in an ajax then you do not need to add it as the href of `<a>`.

Comment: updated code in question for id. In the 2nd line, do u mean remove href? Tried, but the button doesnt work then

Comment: I am assuming that you are not trying to navigate to the url but is trying to call the url using ajax. If that is the case then do not put it in the href as it will change the page.

if you remove the href, and add console.log('button clicked') above the ajax and try clicking the button, then in the console of your browser you should see that the button is "working". so if nothing else is happening after that then you can say that your ajax call is the one that is "broken"

Comment: Removed href, added console.log('button clicked'). There is 'button clicked' in inspect console log, but not export. So, does it means ajax is the problem here?

Comment: its ajax error, not the route error. Thanks for your help